# react-virtualized dynamic table height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-virtualized.

**What I want to achieve:** I want the table's own height to be dynamic, such that the table will grow in height when there are added more rows to my table.

I have used CellMeasurer on the rows to compute the height of each row. It seems like the List from react-table needs a height to know how much it should render, so what is the propper way to calculate the new table height?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify autoHeight prop as stated in [docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `height` from `WindowScroller` component provided by `react-virtualized`

Example:

```
<WindowScroller>
           {({ height, scrollTop}) => (
             <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                {({ width }) => (
                  <Table                   
                    autoHeight
                    height={height}
                    scrollTop={scrollTop}                    
                    width={width}
                    {...otherRequiredProps}
                  >           
                    {/* Columns here*/}
                  </Table>
                )}
              </AutoSizer>
           )}
</WindowScroller>
```

In the above code, I have also used `AutoSizer` component to take container width.